# Is that a way to found out what line code the JVM is currently executing in debug mode

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm, debug-mode

I'm working on a project that take too much time in startup (**in debug mode**) to finally stops at my break points.

The project is huge! and I need to know whats taking so much time everytime i run it so i can disable this blocking treatment in dev environment.

Comment: You can attach a profiler to figure out which operations consume the most time. You can also try to add a bunch of logging statement for some of the higher level operations and see if anything pops up as an outlier.

Comment: When you are already in a debugger, you can simply stop the program execution and see where it is.

Comment: Simple as that! Thank's @Holger!